# Where is the class itself stored at runtime to be used as a reference

Tags: java, c#, memory, class, object

In C# or Java we find that the objects are stored on heap and their reference vars are stored on stack. But at run time where is the class definition stored to be used as a template for creating objects?

Comment: [Where does class, object, reference variable get stored in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13624462/102937)  ... See also https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2010/01/the-java-memory-architecture-1-act/ : *"The **method area** is responsible for storing class information."*

Comment: Starting with Smalltalk, in most OO programming languages (Java included), a class _is_ an object---an instance of a class named `Class`.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, at least in Java I got know about method area but can you suggest me the same for C#?.

Comment: @jameslarge: Perhaps (depending on your definition of "object"), but classes are not stored in memory the same way as instances.

Comment: @JacquesB.  Which language are you speaking of?  Java is one of the languages tagged in the question.  In a running Java program, classes are stored in exactly the same way as instances because classes _are_ instances.  They are instances of the class named `java.lang.Class`.

Comment: @JacquesB, P.S., I am speaking of the Java language as it is specified, and not of any particular implementation of the Java language.  It may be that some particular JVM implementation segregates Class instances from other instances for performance or, to simplify some design issue; but that doesn't matter to a Java application developer.  As far as the application developer is concerned, a Class _behaves_ just like any other instance.

Comment: @jameslarge: The distinction between the method area and heap is part of the Java VM specification: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.4

Comment: That paragraph doesn't say much.  It says a little about how Oracle's JVM actually is implemented, but nothing about how somebody else's JVM _must_ be implemented.  The phrase "method area" hardly appears anywhere else in the whole document.  There's nothing that says how to get a "handle" on the method area, how to inspect it, manage it, etc.  To me, it says nothing more than, "Oh, by the way, _our_ JVM stores byte-codes in a special memory region..."  They don't even bother to tell us _why_ they do that.  If you deleted that section from the spec, nobody would miss it.

Comment: Whether a spec declares a conceptual area in which these are loaded or cached or processed is of little consequence since there are seldom any defined behaviors around them: they are just being conceptually acknowledged.  We should note that the Java/C# "heap" is also conceptual, though has more defined behavior with respect to the objects stored it: their gc, finalization, etc...  Sill the Java/C# heap does not even have to be in a single contiguous run of memory within the native process/program running the virtual machine.

Comment: The OP may be used to prototype-based languages like JavaScript, where there is a master template that new objects are cloned from. Consider this in answers.

Comment: The idea that in C# value types go on the stack (or, as you put it, references to objects go on the stack) is, at best, only sometimes true. See Eric Lippert's blog about that: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class definitions are stored in a separate area (neither stack nor heap) called the **method area**. In .net the corresponding area is called the **Loader Heap**. Data in the method area is written by the class loader, and it is never garbage collected and cannot be deleted.

Comment: Where's the method area located?  Is it itself put on some sort of heap?

Comment: If it's never collected, doesn't that imply that dynamically loaded classes/assemblies are effectively leaked when they're no longer referenced?

Comment: @DeadMG: Yeah, basically. That said, the JVM spec *allows* garbage collection of the method area, it just doesn't mandate it. But I'm not sure when it would be safe to collect a class.

Comment: @DeadMG thats a classic "permgen out of space" issue with class loaders in development servers (where we're always updating the code and reloading the class... but the old one is still there)

Answer (score 1):

A class is not a monolithic template. It is an abstract concept.  It has methods, which are executable code. That code will be in the "code segment". The template you refer to would be a structure that contains initial values for data members and possibly a virtual method table. Those would be in the "data segment". That is, once everything is native code loaded into memory, ready to be executed. Before that (while it is IL or Java byte code), it is all data loaded into allocated memory. So that would be on the heap.

"Method area" as mentioned in a different answer is a Common Language Infrastructure level answer. That is software. Heap and stack are CPU level concepts, as are code segment and data segment.